# Hot to add value to the JS template [blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload]

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've got issue with jQuery File Upload (blueimp).

On uploading files I `insert` file data to DB. Right after that I can get last insert id. The issue: How can i transmit this value from PHP to JavaScript Template?

**To be more clear, I need template like:**

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
   {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
      <div class="template-download fade" id="file-{%=file.id%}">
         <div class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></div>
         ....
      </div>
   {% } %}
</script>
```

where `file.id` is my last insert id that was defined in PHP.

**SOLUTUON**: Function post in class UploadHandler. Add something like

```
$info[$index]->myvar= 'something';
```

then we can use `file.myvar` in template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some extra form data, and I had luck with adding them to the function `handle_file_upload`

```
$file = new stdClass();
$file->name = $this->trim_file_name($name, $type, $index);
$file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow(intval($size));
$file->type = $type;
//add additional post variables here:
$file->title = $_POST['title'][$index];
$file->description = $_POST['description'][$index];
```